# Unable to turn on laptop after installing ubuntu (secure boot)

Tags: ubuntu, boot

I've just bought a new laptop and have attempted to install Ubuntu 14.04 on it.

The laptop is a dell inspiron 3521. After installing Ubuntu the power button does not even do anything.

What is the best way to recover my system?

Is it possible to dual boot Ubuntu? I assume I messed up by not finding out if my new laptop shipped with secure boot enabled.

Comment: Do you mean you cannot see BIOS now?

Comment: No, I can't get to BIOS. Turning it on does nothing. It's totally unresponsive. It's like a brick. I think I might just RMA the unit.. (Hopefully me installing another OS is under warranty)

Comment: If it's easy to do this, I mean run RMA, go for it. By the way I found [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201208-11539/)

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov Do you know if I can run 14.04? I don't know how UEFI works exactly. It is my understanding that 14.04 would need to be shipped with the certificate? On future laptops, can I just disable UEFI/secure boot?

Comment: my understanding no certificates so far. 14.04 in theory should be better. About UEFI/secure boot: [http://askubuntu.com/questions/206950/how-to-understand-ubuntu-uefi-secure-boot-install](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206950/how-to-understand-ubuntu-uefi-secure-boot-install) , [http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)